# I'm confused about the steps involved in finding for which value of $x$ a function is concave down.

Tags: calculus

(Apologies for the silly question, I sincerely searched the other questions on the matter but I honestly couldn't understand how to proceed from here)

For example, if I have to find the value of $x$ that is concave down for $f(x)=x^2 e^x + e^x$ From my understanding, I'd have to find the second derivative of that function.

I think I got to that part just fine, with $f''(x)=(x+1)(x+3)e^x$.

What I'm confused about is that I don't know how to find the values given the point I have arrived. Do I let $x+1$ and $x+3$ equal zero and work from there? Do I just ignore the $e^x$?

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is
$$
f'(x)=(x^2+2x+1)e^x,
$$
the second derivative is
$$
f''(x)=(x^2+4x+3)e^x=(x+1)(x+3)e^x
$$
and you want to find where $f''(x)<0$. Since $e^x>0$ it doesn't contribute to the sign, so you have to solve
$$
(x+1)(x+3)<0
$$
that is satisfied for $-3<x<-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $x$ when $f''(x)<0$. Your solution is actually the set of $x$ values where your graph is concave downwards.